# How to count multiple keys and multiple values in a powershell hash table?

Tags: powershell

I am pretty new to powershell, and I am coming from a lotus notes development and SQL background.

I am looking to do some grouping and counting that seems easy, and I feel like I am over looking something.   I have a list of locations that have different events tagged to them.  I want to be able to group them by locations and event.  For example,

```
$data = import-csv test-data.csv 

$hash = $data | group-object -Property Location -AsHashTable -AsString

--this gives me the top 10 locations with regard to all events

$hash.values.Location | group -noelement |sort count | select -last 10
```

I am looking to drill down into those results to get a more detailed response.

```
<table>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Event</th>
<th>Count</th>
<br>
<tr>PhL</tr>
<tr>Incident</tr>
<tr>5</tr>
<br>
<tr>PhL</tr>
<tr>Accident</tr>
<tr>3</tr>
<br>
<tr>NYC</tr>
<tr>Accident</tr>
<tr>7</tr>
<br>
<tr>PhL</tr>
<tr>Incident</tr>
<tr>3</tr>
</table>
```

I would like to automate the reporting instead of doing this all in excel every week or so.

Edit: $hash.values.location returns a list of locations. The locations can be used as keys and will give me the different events.

The CSV is simple 4 columns: Location, Event, EmployeeID, Date.

The Return Values are: Count by Branch but does not include different types of events

Comment: what does test-date.csv look like? what does `$hash.values.Location | group -noelement |sort count | select -last 10` return?

Comment: $hash.values.location returns a list of locations.  The locations can be used as keys and will give me the different events.  

The CSV is simple 4 columns: Location, Event, EmployeeID, Date.  

The Return Values  are: Count   by Branch  but does not include different types of events.